# Lower bound типов или его эмуляция

Tags: kotlin

Предположим, что делается реализация аналога `Option`/`Some`/`None` из Scala. Упрощенная база делается прямолинейно:

```
sealed class Option<out A> {
    abstract fun isDefined(): Boolean
    abstract fun get(): A
}
class Some<A>(val value: A) : Option<A>() {
    override fun isDefined(): Boolean = true
    override fun get(): A = value
}
object None : Option<Nothing>() {
    override fun isDefined(): Boolean = false
    override fun get(): Nothing = throw NoSuchElementException()
}
```

Но как добавить `getOrElse`? Варианты:

- `abstract fun getOrElse(elseBody: () -> A): A` - нельзя, поскольку `Type parameter A is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'in' position in type () -> A`
- `abstract fun <B>getOrElse(elseBody: () -> B): B` - можно, для `None` работает (`override fun <B>getOrElse(elseBody: () -> B): B = elseBody()`), но для `Some` нельзя написать `override fun <B>getOrElse(elseBody: () -> B): B = value`. Очевидно, что `value` не будет типом `B`

Как-то необходимо в определении абстрактного `getOrElse` связать `A` и `B`, но не как `B : A`, а в обратную сторону.

В Scala для этого используется т.н. lower bound: `final def getOrElse[B >: A](default: => B): B`, но как сделать аналог или эмуляцию lower bound в Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Напрямую, видимо, не получится. Но вполне рабочий вариант через использование расширения (extension). В прямолинейной реализации:

```
fun <A> Option<A>.getOrElse(elseBody: () -> A): A {
    return if (this is Some<A>) {
        this.get()
    }
    else {
        elseBody()
    }
}
```

Работает как нужно.